# What books did schools use to teach BASIC?

Tags: programming, basic, applesoft-basic, books

What books would have been used to teach school aged kids BASIC in a classroom setting back when BASIC was in common use? 8-Bit computers commonly came with tutorials to learn BASIC, like [A Touch of AppleSoft BASIC](https://archive.org/details/A_Touch_of_Applesoft_BASIC_HQ) or [An Introduction to BASIC](https://archive.org/details/Commodore_64_An_Introduction_to_Basic_Part_1). From the late 70's through the early 90's many schools taught BASIC and I would like to harness all their hard work instead of reinventing the wheel. David Brin wrote extensively about why BASIC programming is still useful in [Why Johnny Can't Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20090303091306/http://www.salon.com:80/tech/feature/2006/09/14/basic/).

> The "scripting" languages that serve as entry-level tools for today's
>   aspiring programmers – like Perl and Python – don't make this
>   experience accessible to students in the same way. BASIC was close
>   enough to the algorithm that you could actually follow the reasoning
>   of the machine as it made choices and followed logical pathways. 
>   Repeating this point for emphasis: You could even do it all yourself,
>   following along on paper, for a few iterations, verifying that the dot
>   on the screen was moving by the sheer power of mathematics, alone.
>   Wow!

Clarification: I'm interested in US schools which general used the C64 or the Apple II.
Second Clarification: I've expanded the question to school aged since elementary school is aiming very low.

Comment: Its not relevant to your question but, for sake of expounding, I learned BASIC from the Sinclair ZX81 and Sinclair ZX Spectrum manuals. They're probably still the best explanatory text I've ever read on a computing subject. Their excellence made them worth a mention...well, to me anyway :-)

Comment: From my UK perspective, there was no concerted effort to teach kids of that age any kind of programming.  There was a vague notion of teaching IT skills (mostly involving using word processors and spreadsheets), but I didn't encounter any formal instruction in programming until much later (i.e. after I'd worked it out for myself).  Which is a shame, because UK schools generally had BBC micros, which had a much better implementation of BASIC than either the C64 or Apple II.

Comment: The problem with BASIC on the microcomputers as a teaching tool is not BASIC itself per se (folks love to hate on BASIC), but simply the lack high level constructs to make the development engaging. For example, if you wanted to animate a sprite on a C64, it's mostly about detailed data formats, PEEK, POKE, and FOR loops. You go from entry level computer programming to detailed computer architecture in 2 lessons. Imagine trying to explain the code at the bottom of https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Sprite#Programming_sprites_in_BASIC to your child. Other than that, it's PRINT, INPUT, FOR and math.

Comment: ... and you won't accept an answer with modern lesson plans for a modern BASIC? If you were willing to, resources are at https://www.fuze.co.uk/worksheets-tutorials.html and downloads are at https://www.fuze.co.uk/download-fuze.html — use a Linux or Windows PC, a Raspberry Pi or an ASUS Tinker Board to host. To skip straight to a sample lesson plan, see page 3 of https://www.fuzebasic.com/bin/worksheets/FCS_BOOK_1_FINAL.pdf (EDIT: quick bluffer's guide: Key Stage 2 is ages 8 to 11, Key Stage 3 is ages 11 to 14, that's for general classroom use so your child may well be more capable)

Comment: I'm focused on AppleSoft BASIC because I've got a IIgs and MicroSoft written BASIC variants were the rule in the US.

Comment: @WillHartung A diagram with a grid and numbers on it, and labelling it as an advanced technique. Very hard to pull off, but with a few months of encouragement and learning one of the kids might get over all of the usual stuff that's been set and make it work. And that's encouraging for the rest of them; they go "wow!" and then want to learn more. Alternatively, you could use BBC BASIC and named subroutines to simplify it for them. Alas, we've missed our chance to teach the youth about raw memory I/O...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It's not just a grid of numbers, it's the underlying architecture and machine design that manifests what that grid is, and what goes in to it. You're also leaping from simple logic constructs to number systems, base conversion, data encoding, etc. Combined with the typically low level of abstraction common in historic BASIC programs (for all sorts of reasons). drawSprite("sprite,gif", 10, 10) I think is easier to understand than a string of POKE statements to arbitrary addresses.

Comment: @WillHartung I wasn't sure of the specific architecture... I have found that grid(s) of addresses overlaying an example sprite, with annotations for what the data means, as well as a table for non-graphical data to be a very good way of explaining the underlying architecture of sprites on all but the strangest systems.

Comment: Please teach the language with a proper debugger so he/she can step through, inspect variables and so on. It gives a tremendous advantage over those who try to learn a language without the proper tools.

Comment: "[It is practically impossible to teach good programming to students that have had a prior exposure to BASIC: as potential programmers they are mentally mutilated beyond hope of regeneration.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra#How_do_we_tell_truths_that_might_hurt?_(1975))" -- Edsger Dijkstra

Comment: @jameslarge given that innumerable great programmers got their start using BASIC on micros, it obvious that Dijkstra isn't as wise as he thinks he is.

Comment: BASIC was the first programming language I learned. But I figured if I didn't quote him, somebody else would.

Comment: In my experience, unlearning BASIC in order to learn a serious language is significantly easier than unlearning C to learn C++.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin - I'd disagree that Python doesn't make the same functions as accessible to students. [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/) and [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle) are powerful yet simple. On the Raspberry Pi, [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) gives the simplest possible way of talking to digital I/O

Comment: Not in the US but in Canada.. at elementary level age 9/10 or so we had the science teacher doing after school programming on a TRS80.  No books, just his lessons.  Probably his own project.  In high school it was Apple IIs and PCs again no books, just the teachers' own notes in formal classes.  The Apple IIs were basic and the PCs were pascal.   At home and via computer clubs it was the zx81 manual combined with magazine listings that in large part were understandable even to a 10-12 year old that really got me going.

Comment: FWIW the quote you give is nonsense. Maybe it makes more sense in context, but the web link is giving me 503 at the moment. Anyway, there's no reason why you can't hand execute a Python program and follow the logic with pencil and paper. I think the real barriers are more to do with the environment. Modern programs take maybe hundreds of man years of effort and have really nice graphical interfaces. Compare that to the output of a Python program in a terminal and the whole thing looks hopeless to the beginner.

Comment: @JeremyP You can write simple scripts today or simple JavaScript but you don't come close to what _real_ programs look like. On an Apple II (or C64 etc) BASIC programs look a lot like everything else, and a number of commercial programs were written in BASIC. I found it very satisfying to write things that looked in my eyes as good as what professionals did. When I switched to GUI programming on the Mac those programs were huge compared to the starter BASIC programs. My first Pascal application had a good 4k of code to handle events and menus before getting to anything else.

Comment: Illustrating Basic by Donald Alcock was quite popular in the UK when my kids were growing up.  Superb book, very well illustrated and kid friendly.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin Yes, back in the early 80's, the gap between professional software (at least for microcomputers) and what I - a teenage hobbyist - could write seemed very much smaller than it does today.

Comment: I learned BASIC on a time-shared HP minicomputer in 1972, long before 8-bit micros existed.  I think the only resource available was the HP manual.

Comment: Anecdotally, I learned BASIC on Apple ][+ in a class in high school, in Michigan, USA, in 1981-1982.  There were no textbooks.  There were probably photocopied/mimeographed note4s, but I don't recall them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer different question which is assumed by the original question; I am the author of the textbook in informatics, and think answering this way would be appropriate.

It is not that BASIC was great language to program, or people were just writing great books in the past, but now having difficulties with that. Consider the following:

1. BASIC was one of the first "consumer" programming language. Programming the way explained in the book was new to the wide audience, and there was a big interest in that - because it was new and it was perceived as having great potential;
2. If you would carefully examine the books of that time, they were focusing on content of the programming - algorithms - rather than quickly jumping to the button-pressing "angry birds" behavior in front of the keyboard. Programmer was that person who was able to devise working and more or less optimal algorithm to achieve the result using logic. These days programmer is the one who knows buzzword operators of buzzword programming language;
3. People were willing to study basics of the programming, and were interested in programming as a science subject. Programs of those times are masterpieces doing a lot of stuff within constrained RAM, ROM, graphics, I/O etc. Modern programming is more about making up something *acceptable* of the "bricks" of already existing functionality into the functional application.

So there're several mandatory things to get good future programmer -

1. genuine interest in the subject;
2. knowing the basics of the logic and at least one programming language at low and high level;
3. be set for the quality - not that perfection, but for the continuous quality in the whole process of software development involving not only coding, but also starting with proper and scalable architecture, proper platform/hardware selection, thoughtful requirements drafting, and execution (coding and testing).

Good book will not change the status quo unless targeted individual is exhibiting properties above.

Comment: Very perceptive answer, David Brin says, "Typing in a simple algorithm yourself, seeing exactly how the computer calculates and iterates in a manner you could duplicate with pencil and paper -- say, running an experiment in coin flipping, or making a dot change its position on a screen, propelled by math and logic, and only by math and logic: All of this is priceless." Modern programming books are mostly, here is how you do strings in this language, now here is a web server in 20 lines. The older books focused much more on the algorithms and logic. I want my kid to know why programming works.

Comment: Very few micro BASIC books had any focus on algorithms, so maybe using your IIgs + AppleSoft approach isn't ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Not a book but a (relatively) current website, with lesson plans, in AppleSoft BASIC: [20 lessons to teach your 12-year old how to start programming](http://www.hoist-point.com/applesoft_basic_tutorial.htm)

Answer (score 2):

"101 BASIC COMPUTER GAMES" also known as "BASIC COMPUTER GAMES" (the "101" in the title was not clear on some version of the cover art).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC_Computer_Games

Perhaps that's a bit earlier than your timespan of "late 70's to early 90's", but it's certainly what a lot of kids (and adults) learned from in the mid 70's to early 80's.

And yes, "self-directed learning" and the "non-directive teaching model" were popular among young teachers in the mid 70's to early 80's.

Answer (score 1):

Programming in BASIC for business by Bruce Bosworth is the one I used in High School:

https://archive.org/details/programminginbas0000bosw

Elementary school students would have been learning LOGO at the time not BASIC.